# Is there a way of removing "reorder" option from Magento 1.9 by changing configuration?

Tags: magento-1.9, reorder

Like in title, is there a way of removing "reorder" option from **Magento ver. 1.9** in the configuration section?

I know I can remove it using `XML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log in to the admin panel.
2. Go to **System** > **Configuration** > **Sales (Sales)** section.
3. Under **Reorder**, Change **Allow Reorder** to **`No`**.
4. Save the configuration and refresh cache.

That's all.

Comment: Great. I knew I seen it somewhere, couldn't find it...